# Why does this code skip adding to the list object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This code is supposed to add random numbers into an object, creating a list of items with unique id's.  The code checks each rnd # to see if it is already in the list.

Works fine, but after a random amount of time, it will add to the counter, but skip adding the item to the list.

Am I just missing something here?

Thanks

jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jelder/en0pmdtb/

```
console.log("Starting...");
var rnd = 0;
var list = {};
var count = 0;

var loop = setInterval(function() {
    //Genereate rnd number and check if it is in the list
    check1: while(true){
        rnd = parseInt(Math.random()*10000);
        if (Object.keys(list).indexOf(rnd)>=0){
            console.log('dupe:'+count);
            continue check1;
        } else {
            break check1;
        }
    }

    //Add to list
    list[rnd] = {
        'a':count
    };

    //Add to counter
    count++;

    //Debug - Count not mactching list length
    if (count != Object.keys(list).length) { 
        console.log(count + " : "+Object.keys(list).length);
        clearInterval(loop);
    }

    //Stop at limit
    if(count >= 11000) {
        console.log('hit limit');
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
},50);
```

Comment: your code is destined to fail anyway - you can't generate 11000 random numbers from a set of 10000 possibilities

Comment: All of `list`s keys are strings, `rnd` is a number. Use `String(rnd)`. Edit: actually just do what @Bravo said below.

Comment: by the way `if (Object.keys(list).indexOf(rnd)>=0)` is quicker if you just check `if (list[rnd])`

Comment: @Mason - if he fixes the test, he's doomed to failure because of my first comment :p

Comment: @Bravo I'm too tired right now to think about that. I found the bug, mission accomplished XD

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? Generating random numbers or test some processing speed?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. Looking at resource usage on some older equipment.

Comment: @JonathanElder - you realise your code will eventually become an infinite loop ... your `hit limit` test condition need only be `10001` and the code will definitely become an infinite loop

Comment: @Bravo I'm aware. This was just proof of concept. Seeing how the older system handles making multiple checks and re-checks for the duplicate. Thank you.